# Javascript toUpperCase() method

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to Javascript and have a question on the toUpperCase() method:

`let firstName = prompt("Please enter your first name.")`

If I wanted to output statement above to upper case, I use the toUpeprCase() method:

`firstName = firstName.toUpperCase();`

However, if I simply wrote the below code and do not re-assign firstName like in above, then first name doesn't turn to upper case:

`firstName.toUpperCase();`

Why is it that I need to "re-assign" firstName in order for it to turn upper case? It is very hard to remember this because logically, you'd think just writing firstName.toUpperCase(); would do the trick.

Thank you

Comment: Strings are immutable. That method *returns a new string*.

Comment: Strings are immutable and returns a new string. It helps us to keep original values safe however if you don't want to write new line you can just code `prompt("Please enter your first name.").toUpperCase();`.

Answer (score 3):

[`.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) returns the string value converted to uppercase, so, you need to reassign it.

Answer (score 2):

> The [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) method **returns** the calling string value converted to uppercase (the value will be converted to a string if it isn't one).

So you should reassign the value to the variable to override the previous value

---

This could be usefull if you want to keep the original value, for example:

```js
const string = 'Hello, I\'m an example!';
const upper = string.toUpperCase();

console.log(string);
console.log(upper);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.toUpperCase()` method is a method of string which *returns* the uppercase version of given string. It does not modify the existing string. Thus you need to reassign it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase.